# Use GaussianProcessRegressor with precomputed kernel in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I am trying to use the `GaussianProcessRegressor` in scikit-learn with some graph kernels computed by the grakel software. Below is my code for a 5-fold cross-validation on 100 graph data. For the sake of testing convenience, I have commented out all graph-related lines and use random kernel matrices and `y` values instead.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor as GPR
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
#from grakel.kernels import WeisfeilerLehman
import numpy as np

def Kfold_CV_GPR(Gs, y, n_iter=4, n_splits=5, random_state=None):
    random_state = check_random_state(random_state)
    kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, random_state=random_state, shuffle=True)
    errors = []
    for train_idxs, test_idxs in kf.split(y):
#        gk = WeisfeilerLehman(n_iter=n_iter, normalize=True)
#        K_train = gk.fit_transform(Gs[train_idxs])
#        K_test = gk.transform(Gs[test_idxs])
        K_train = np.random.randn(80, 80)
        K_test = np.random.randn(20, 80)
        gpr = GPR(kernel='precomputed')
        gpr.fit(K_train, y[train_idxs])
        y_pred = gpr.predict(K_test)
        rmse = mean_squared_error(y[test_idxs], y_pred, squared=False)
        errors.append(rmse)
    return -np.mean(errors)

score = Kfold_CV_GPR(Gs=None, y=np.random.randn(100, ), n_iter=4, n_splits=5)
print(score)
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object ''precomputed'' (type <class 'str'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn
estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' method.
```

When I change `sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor` to `sklearn.svm.SVR` (support vector regression), my code doesn't throw any error, but it will run forever for some reason. I also tested classifers like `sklearn.svm.SVC` and my code is working fine.

Anyone know how to use precomputed kernel in a scikit-learn's `GaussianProcessRegressor`?